# Windows 7, Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a hp Pavilion dm3 laptop which crashed with a BSOD.  It won't start up in windows so I unwittingly decided to create a Ubuntu start-up usb disc.

I then proceeded to insert it into my laptop and it went to installing ubuntu.  But it came across a fatal error.  Now I cant even get into anything.  :(  Have I lost all my previous desktop files?

What do I do now?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was said fatal error? What happens when you put the CD in the laptop and try again?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Just FYI, error messages aren't just random jibberish that gets spit out at you for fun. They do actually mean something, and if you can replicate the issue, try to photograph them so you can copy them here in an [edit] to your question. Hope you didn't lose anything important. ;(

Comment: Next time this happens I suggest you run Ubuntu in live mode, rather than trying to install it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything further,

1. Just boot in with any linux live cd you have.
2. Immediately backup all the important files from the drive where you were installing Ubuntu. (You can find your desktop files in 'C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\' )

Next, if you are willing to keep only ubuntu on your laptop,

1. Backup first and format the drive on which you want to install(can do it with the booted live cd).
2. Install ubuntu this time via Live CD.

If you want to have Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu, its better to first install Windows 7 and then install Ubuntu.

Comment: When I turn on the computer on now, it is just a black screen.  I can't replicate the screen anymore.  How do I get a linux live cd?  I have now made myself a bootable Windows7 cd, but when I put it into the computer, It keeps saying "Automatic boot in XX seconds..."  where XX is 10 counting down to 01 but it keeps looping so from 01 secs, it goes to 10 secs.  What now?   I had hit the tab button, it says: "> /ubukern initrd=/ubninit"

Comment: Sorry i am answering late, maybe till now you might have got the solution. But if your win7 CD is giving above error, high chance it might be corrupted. Its better to follow above steps by booting from your Ubuntu in live mode. If not having the ubuntu cd, download [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts) iso from another pc and burn it on a disk then boot into your bugged pc from this disk.